# How can I distribute highly confidential keys for a symmetric cipher?

Tags: tls, key-management, rsa, key-exchange, key

Say I want to exchange a key with someone for a symmetric cipher (say AES) without meeting them in person. What would be the most secure way to do this over the Internet? My first instinct would be using a custom RSA channel over HTTPS to provide the most security.
I need the most future-proof method possible. (keep in mind this only needs to be done once, so even an "insane" method can be considered an answer.)

Comment: The main question is on how you can authenticate the other person in order to make sure that the correct person gets the key and not some attacker. Unfortunately, your question currently provides no clue about this. To show some possible options: you have already a certificate or public key of this person, you know his/her voice, you have some trusted party who knows the person ... If you have no previous contact and nothing what you can base some trust or authentication on then there is no safe way, since an attacker could claim to be the other person and you could not verify this.

Comment: Since your question is tagged TLS, I am wondering why you didn't just use TLS for that, given that this is exactly the problem TLS is trying to solve.

Comment: I do use TLS (HTTPS) as I mentioned above, but an attacker could just keep the encrypted copy of the message and decrypt it in a year (when computing power doubles again). I am assuming that the attacker is _patient_. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score -1):

For your problem, the easy way coming to my mind is [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy): both the sender and the receiver exchange asymmetric keys and can then send each other private messages. You can validate each other pulic key other the phone to make sure no one messed with it (see [MitM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)).

For all I know, using WhatsApp or Telegram might also be secure enough as they use end-to-end encryption (the message decryption keys are on your phones only).

Comment: *both the sender and the receiver exchange asymmetric keys* - well, or just "exchange symmetric keys", and the problem is solved. :)

Comment: Well, public keys in the nature is fine, but you don't want your symmetric key lying in plain view.

Comment: *Confidentiality* is not important with public keys, that is true, but *integrity* is. The described step to validate public keys, might as well just be the "exchange symmetric keys".

Comment: I admit that, but once you have a secure channel, you can exchange further information. Moreover, when exchanging a symmetric key, you would have to make no mistakes, while you could probably skip a character/use a [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#PGP_fingerprint) to make it easier with public keys.

Comment: Fingerprint is 160 bits, AES keys are often 128 bits. Skipping a few characters is not a good security practice. Konrad Rieck describes in "Fuzzy Fingerprints" article how to generate fingerprints that have matching beginnings and endings (which is what's most often compared).

Comment: Anyway, that didn't really address the problem I have with this answer, which can be summarised into "to have a secure channel you need a secure channel".

Comment: Well, I must agree. But to answer the question, how to established a secure channel? And is phone a secure channel? If yes, then send symmetric key in a call. If no, exchange asymmetric keys, then symmetric.

Comment: If you exchange asymmetric keys over insecure channel, what prevents an attacker tampering with them? You're back to square one. This can be resolved with web-of-trust or PKI, but your answer doesn't mention either.

Comment: PGP relies on web-of-trust / you can still validate keys over the phone: no confidentiality needed.

Comment: If we assume that the attacker is a patient attacker (Who can wait a year for computing power to double, or for QM computers to be built), PGP does work, but eventually, it will be broken and the symmetric keys will be compromised. I can easily use a PKI or a web-of-trust technique to verify that the asymmetric keys are correct, (so we assume that PGP is okay for now) but what I need is to future-proof the message as much as possible, since the attacker who wants to read this communication can and will wait. PGP + TLS is the best bet I can think of.